# Source Recommendation on Meaning of It All

Tags: product-recommendation

I am reading through this book that represents all the different Jewish opinions on what our purpose is in this world. Each one brings a certain set of actions that God wants us to do. However, they don't explain what the end goal of these actions are/ why does God need us to do these actions. Any recommendations on Jewish sources on the topic?

Comment: You could make this question a great deal more tractable by [edit]ing in more details about the type of material you're seeking. Primary sources? Contemporary book? Hebrew? English? Including more information about the book you're currently reading could also offer helpful clues about the ideal follow-on.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what book you're reading.

Comment: There is a nice survey of opinions found among the sages of the mishnah and the talmud in R Jack Bieler's The Great Principle of the Torah: Examining Seven Talmudic Claims to the Defining Principles of Judaism (2016). https://amzn.to/2PA4e2m

Highly recommended.

Comment: If you want one comparatively more recent answer to the question, Rav Shimon Shkop has a perspective that really focuses on the interpersonal. (He created us to have someone to be good to. We connect to G-d in order to better share His Good with others.) I wrote a book analyzing it (and extrapolating from what he wrote) that was published by Moasica last February, "Widen Your Tent". https://amzn.to/36KkZxF

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Chapter 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Messilat_Yesharim.1?lang=bi) of [Mesillat Yesharim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesillat_Yesharim) by [R. Moshe Chaim Luzzato](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto).

The full Hebrew text with an English translation is available at sefaria.org [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Messilat_Yesharim.1?lang=bi). Here is an English translation of the first paragraph to give you a taster:

> The foundation of piety and the root of perfect service [of G-d] is for a man to clarify and come to realize as truth what is his obligation in his world and to what he needs to direct his gaze and his aspiration in all that he toils all the days of his life.

Comment: How does he answer the question? He just says that our goal is to find the answer, no?

Comment: @Voctave The answer starts with the next sentence

Comment: @Voctave He describes throughout the chapter what the purpose is. A key quote towards the end: “Thus it is proper that all of a man's inclination be solely to the blessed Creator and that all of his actions great or small have no other purpose than to draw closer to G-d, blessed be He, and to break down all the barriers separating him from his Master, which are all the matters of physicality and the things dependent on them, until he is drawn towards the blessed G-d like iron is drawn to a magnet...For his coming to this world is only for this purpose, namely, to attain this closeness...”

Comment: Would highly recommend Rav Aryeh Kaplan’s “World of Love.” It explains this whole topic very nicely - not just what the purpose is but why that is conceptually - and is available online here: http://www.aish.com/jl/p/wl/?mobile=yes

Comment: @user5173 Why not post your comment as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vain as Joel K.’s answer, I’d suggest to look in RAMCHAL’s Derech Hashem first section where he is much lengthier on this topic. (Particularly chapters 1-4).

Comment: Maybe add https://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem%2C_Part_One%2C_On_the_Purpose_of_Creation ?